# Can you access properties/methods of parent window from the child?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

if I create a popup in JavaScript I can access its properties:

```
var myWin = window.open("test.htm");
myWin.property1;
```

but my question is, can I access properties/methods of parent window from the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just do `window.opener`, this will get you access to the parent window. For example, to refresh the parent window, you can do

```
window.opener.location.refresh();
```

Comment: wow that is almost to easy. I feel like I should of already known that. Thanks.